# Emitting functions up to parent to refresh props?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

I am struggling a bit for a decent way of handling passing data down when using frameworks like React and Vue. For a Vue project I'm working on,  I've been using this approach and want to make sure it makes sense.

Right now, I have my parent make a "Master" API call to get the whole `Customer` object.  I pass `Customer` as a prop to the child component.  The child component uses the value of `Customer.address` to prefill an input field.  If that field is updated, the child makes an api call to post the new data, then I emit a function back up to the parent to call the "Master" function and get a new copy of the Customer object so that the props it passes down are refreshed.  Does this make sense?

**Parent.vue**

```
<template>

    <Child 
        :customer = "this.customer"
        @handleGetCustomerData = "getCustomerData"
        >

    </Child>

</template>


<script>

    export default {

        data() {
            customer = {}
        }
        mounted() {
            this.getCustomerData()
        },
        methods: {

            getCustomerData: function() {
                axios
                    .get('/api/customer')
                    .then(response => {
                        this.customer = response
                    };
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

**Child.vue**

```
<template>

    <div>
      <input :value="customer.address" ref="address">
        <button
            v-on:click="updateAddress()">
            Update Address
        </button>

    </div>

</template>

<script>
    export default {

        props: {
            customer:  {type: Object}
        },

        methods: {

            updateAddress() {
                axios.post('/api/address', { 
                address: this.$refs.address.value
            })
            .then(response => {
                this.handleGetCustomerData()
            });

            handleGetCustomerData() {
                this.$emit('handleGetCustomerData')
            }

        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes sense, of course. We use **props** to communicate `parent -> child` and **events** to communicate `child -> parent`.

You're doing it correctly but you could get some problems and complex debugging calling API inside your child component. I would just `$emit` some "updateAddress" passing `this.$refs.address.value` as param and calling API inside parent component.

Doing it, you can centralize API callings and refreshs, updating childs' data always via props.

Hope it helps! [Here is a great article about it](https://medium.com/@sky790312/about-vue-2-parent-to-child-props-af3b5bb59829).

Comment: Thanks Matheus!  My only concern with my approach is that after making API calls to update data, I am emitting an event to the parent to make the "master" api call to 'get' and refresh the props so they are passed down with updated values.   Would a "less expensive" way of saving an API GET call to get the refreshed data be to just to change that value if the update api succeeds?   For example, I update the address and instead of calling a GET right after I update to pass the props to the child to reflect , I just set address value to whatever I updated it to? I hope I am explaining it correct

Comment: Yes, it is a solution! Once you know your post returned success and what value you sent, you can just update child's local data manually. But it could cause some unecessary problems since you would have "two sources" of information (API and your manually changed local data).

Of course there are situations this cost is worth it (depending on network performance, etc.) but usually I see no problem doing another request inasmuch as data was updated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Vue but in React I would **not** let the child handle the API requests at all. The logic should be in one place (in parent) and then the flow would look something like that:

- (Parent) Get the object and pass as a prop
- (Child) When you update the field, the child runs a **callback** from a parent
- (Parent) Executes the api request and then get's the updated object and updates the props